# JS simple function call is not working

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, codeigniter

im new to codeginiter and its developing. i used dropbox (html select box) when i pressed option there. i need to  trigger a alert box.in oder to do that i used following code. But it didnt work on me. and i could find the mistake i've done please help me.

```
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta content="text/html;charset=utf-8" http-equiv="Content-Type">
        <meta content="utf-8" http-equiv="encoding">

        <title>Ask Questions</title>
        <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
        <meta name="description" content="">
        <meta name="author" content="">


        <link href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
        <link href="<?php echo base_url(); ?>css/style.css" rel="stylesheet"> 

<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>js/jquery.min.js">

                   // untill select catogory tags are disabled


                   function activate_match()
                   {
                      // var tnmt_id = "hip hure";
                       alert("tested");
                       //Get the id of the tournament selected in the list
                   }


</script>


    </head>

<body>
        <div class="container">
            <p class="help-block">
                How to Ask </br>
                Is your question about DIY ? </br>
                We prefer questions that can be answered, not just discussed.<br>
                Provide details. Share your experience. </br>

            </p>


            <div class="form-group">

                <?php
                echo form_open('homepage/askquestionview');
                echo validation_errors();
                ?>  
            </div>

            <p> </p>



            <div class="form-group">


                <select name="cat" id="cat" onchange="activate_match()">
<?php
                   foreach($catogories as $cat) {
                    echo'<option value="' . $cat . '">' . $cat . '</option>';
                }
                ?>

                </select>




            </div>

            <div class="form-group">
                <p>
                    Description: <br/>

                    <textarea name="decription" rows="5" cols="100"> </textarea>
                </p>
            </div>



            <p></p>                

            <div class="form-group">
                Declare new Tags:<br/>

                <input type="text" value="" name="tag">
                </p>
            </div>

        </div>                             <p>
            <input type="submit"  class="btn btn-success btn-block" value="Post Your Question" id="postQuestion">
        </p>
        <?php echo form_close(); ?>


    </body>


</html>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to have two separate `script` tags:

```
<script src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
   function activate_match() {
       // var tnmt_id = "hip hure";
       alert("tested");
       //Get the id of the tournament selected in the list
   }
</script>
```

If `script` has `src` attribute its inner content is ignored. So the first script is to load jQuery, and the second to declare you functions.

Answer (score 0):

You should not be using inline javascript. Since you have jQuery available this should do the trick:

```
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('#cat').change(function(){
        alert('Tested! Current select value is: ' + $(this).val());
    });
});
```

Also, it is required to use separate script tag for your custom code, and separate for including files - you have embeded your function inside jQuerys script tags and thats why it is not working.

Answer (score 0):

**change in html**

```
<select name="cat" id="cat" onchange="activate_match(this.value)">
<?php
                   foreach($catogories as $cat) {
                    echo'<option value="' . $cat . '">' . $cat . '</option>';
                }
                ?>

 </select>
```

**In your script**

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="<?php echo base_url(); ?>js/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
                   // untill select catogory tags are disabled


                   function activate_match(id)
                   {
                      // var tnmt_id = "hip hure";
                       alert(id);
                       //Get the id of the tournament selected in the list
                   }


</script>
```